# Include module in a class within the module

Tags: ruby, recursion, namespaces, include

I have two classes. I want to namespace them. I also have a bit of functionality that they share.   I do something like this:

```
module Talker
  def say_bye
    puts 'bye'
  end

  class Bob
    include Talker
    def say_yo
      puts 'yo'
    end
  end

  class Tom
    include Talker
    def say_hello
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end
```

These are all valid method calls.

```
Talker::Bob.new.say_yo
Talker::Bob.new.say_bye
Talker::Tom.new.say_hello
Talker::Tom.new.say_bye
```

I was told: "This `include` is going to include `Bob` again. You should close the `Talker` module before starting a class that includes `Talker`." Can somebody explain to me if I'm doing something that results in unexpected ruby behavior or is considered taboo? Is it a bad practice to include a module like this from inside a class within that module? What might be a criticism for this pattern? Should I use inheritance here?

Comment: Are you sure `Bob.new.say_yo`, etc. are valid (from the main environment)?

Comment: Your example does not produce the error you get

Comment: Edited: The calls didn't work because I didn't have the namespace in front of the classes.  The question isn't "why doesn't this work" or "why does it error"?  It works, and without error.  The questions are if A) is it okay to do this? And B) is it doing anything bad I don't know about behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The include ends up being somewhat recursive.  The code above will do things like this:

```
Talker::Bob::Bob
Talker::Bob::Tom
Talker::Bob::Bob::Bob::Tom::Bob::Tom
```

And that is not something to have.  So he was right when he said it would re-include the other classes in the module into each class that includes the module.